# Mantener caracteristicas en un control luego de hacer un PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controller

Saludos. Resulta que tengo un `Textbox` que cuando pierde el foco cambia su color de fondo, todo esto gracias a una funcion que tengo por allá en `JavaScript`. Mas adelante tengo otro `Textbox` que hace un `PostBack` que necesito para una consulta a una base de datos, y he aqui el problema:

cuando ese segundo `TextBox` hace `PostBack`, el color de fondo del primero pierde su propiedad que habia adquirido gracias a la funcion de `JavaScript`. Y tiene sentido, lo se.

Pero ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer que el PostBack no afecte las caracteristicas de los controles que van adquiriendo desde el lado del cliente? ¿O quiza haciendo algo en el `Page_Load`? Y si la respuesta esta en esto ultimo, no se exactamente qué.

Para hacerme entender un poco mejor, he intentado esto en un `script`:

```
 document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML= "Nuevo_texto";
```

Lo anterior cambia el texto de un `Label`, ¿No es asi?

Hasta aqui, normal, pero si luego hago un `PostBack`, el `Label` toma su valor predeterminado.

¿Como evito esto? ¿Es posible?

Comment: puedes poner que tienes en el `Page_Load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en como pude solucionarlo fue guardando el estado del control en otro control del servidor, como por ejemplo un campo `HiddenField`. Siempre que se haga un cambio en tu control le agregas como atributo al control del server el cambio. Al momento de hacer el postback lees la informacion del control y lo aplicas a tu control.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="campo_nombre_estilo" runat="server />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nombreTextBox" />
<button type="button" onclick="modificarEstilo()">Cambiar estilo</button>
```

JS:

```
function modificarEstilo()
{
  document.getElementById("<%=campo_nombre_estilo.ClientId%>").attr("background", "red");
}
```

Entonces en el `Page_Load`, al hacer postback lees los attributos del `HiddenField` y se lo aplicas al control:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     //...
   }

  nombreTextBox.Styles.Add("background", campo_nombre_estilo.Attributes["background"]);
```

}

Al hacerl `PostBack`, webforms no envia la informacion de estilo de cada elemento al servidor por lo pesado que seria cada request de tanta informacion.